# find regions in a segment without annotation given a table with coordinates

Tags: r, dataframe, coordinates, bioinformatics, tidyverse

I'm trying to figure out how to find non-annotated regions in proteins.

I have a groupable table which contains unidimensional coordinates in a protein, that means, a lot of piece to the same segment but almost aways between two segments there is an empty space (but not always).

If I have this

```
structure(list(acc = c("AAF73695.1", "NP_224303.2", "WP_010882745.1", 
"ABG85315.1", "ABG85315.1", "ABG85315.1"), domain = c("Pkinase", 
"Pkinase", "Pkinase", "sCache_like", "HAMP", "PAS"), start = c(4, 
4, 4, 30, 178, 242), end = c(287, 287, 287, 142, 231, 341), evalue = c(3.8e-41, 
3.8e-41, 3.8e-41, 0.00064, 1.4e-09, 0.0038), len = c(800, 800, 
800, 800, 800, 800)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  acc            domain      start   end   evalue   len
  <chr>          <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 AAF73695.1     Pkinase         4   287 3.80e-41   800
2 NP_224303.2    Pkinase         4   287 3.80e-41   800
3 WP_010882745.1 Pkinase         4   287 3.80e-41   800
4 ABG85315.1     sCache_like    30   142 6.40e- 4   800
5 ABG85315.1     HAMP          178   231 1.40e- 9   800
6 ABG85315.1     PAS           242   341 3.80e- 3   800
```

given this, I'd like to get:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 6
   acc            domain      start   end   evalue   len
   <chr>          <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 AAF73695.1     empty           1      3 0.         800
 2 AAF73695.1     Pkinase         4    287 3.80e-41   800
 3 AAF73695.1     empty         288    800 0.         800
 4 ABG85315.1     empty           1     29 0.        1000
 5 ABG85315.1     sCache_like    30    142 6.40e- 4  1000
 6 ABG85315.1     empty         143    177 0.        1000
 7 ABG85315.1     HAMP          178    231 1.40e- 9  1000
 8 ABG85315.1     empty         232    241 0.        1000
 9 ABG85315.1     PAS           242    341 3.80e- 3  1000
10 ABG85315.1     empty         342   1000 0.        1000
11 NP_224303.2    empty           1      3 0.         300
12 NP_224303.2    Pkinase         4    287 3.80e-41   300
13 NP_224303.2    empty         288    300 0.         300
14 WP_010882745.1 empty           1      3 3.80e-41   300
15 WP_010882745.1 Pkinase         4    287 3.80e-41   300
16 WP_010882745.1 empty         288    300 0.         300
```

using tidyvers I'm trying something like this

```
df %>% 
  group_by(acc) %>%
  arrange(start, end) %>%
  mutate(
    domain = "empty",
    start = end + 1,
    end = lead(start - 1, default = len[1),
    evalue = 0
    ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct() %>%
  bind_rows( df ) %>%
  arrange(acc, start, end)
```

But I got a wrong result, this:

```
structure(list(acc = c("AAF73695.1", "AAF73695.1", "ABG85315.1", 
"ABG85315.1", "ABG85315.1", "ABG85315.1", "ABG85315.1", "ABG85315.1", 
"NP_224303.2", "NP_224303.2", "WP_010882745.1", "WP_010882745.1"
), domain = c("Pkinase", "empty", "sCache_like", "empty", "HAMP", 
"empty", "PAS", "empty", "Pkinase", "empty", "Pkinase", "empty"
), start = c(4, 288, 30, 143, 178, 232, 242, 342, 4, 288, 4, 
288), end = c(287, 800, 142, 231, 231, 341, 341, 800, 287, 800, 
287, 800), evalue = c(3.8e-41, 0, 0.00064, 0, 1.4e-09, 0, 0.0038, 
0, 3.8e-41, 0, 3.8e-41, 0), len = c(800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 
800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
# A tibble: 12 x 6
   acc            domain      start   end   evalue   len
   <chr>          <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 AAF73695.1     Pkinase         4   287 3.80e-41   800
 2 AAF73695.1     empty         288   800 0.         800
 3 ABG85315.1     sCache_like    30   142 6.40e- 4   800
 4 ABG85315.1     empty         143   231 0.         800
 5 ABG85315.1     HAMP          178   231 1.40e- 9   800
 6 ABG85315.1     empty         232   341 0.         800
 7 ABG85315.1     PAS           242   341 3.80e- 3   800
 8 ABG85315.1     empty         342   800 0.         800
 9 NP_224303.2    Pkinase         4   287 3.80e-41   800
10 NP_224303.2    empty         288   800 0.         800
11 WP_010882745.1 Pkinase         4   287 3.80e-41   800
12 WP_010882745.1 empty         288   800 0.         800
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you need.  It creates a summary dataframe with all possible starts and ends as list columns, and then `unnest`s them, using these values to repopulate the original data (or `NA`s) via a `left_join`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- df %>% group_by(acc) %>% 
  summarise(start2=list(sort(unique(c(1,start,end+1)))),    #all possible starts
            end=list(sort(unique(c(start-1,end,len))))) %>% #all possible ends
  rename(start=start2) %>%                                  #avoids overwrite in prev line
  unnest(c(start, end)) %>%                                 #expand lists
  left_join(df) %>%                                         #join df data (rest will be NA)
  mutate(domain = replace_na(domain,"empty")) %>%           #replace NA with 'empty'
  group_by(acc) %>%                                         #summarise destroyed first grouping
  fill(evalue, len, .direction = "downup")                  #fill NA values

df2
# A tibble: 16 x 6
# Groups:   acc [4]
   acc            start   end domain        evalue   len
   <chr>          <dbl> <dbl> <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>
 1 AAF73695.1         1     3 empty       3.80e-41   800
 2 AAF73695.1         4   287 Pkinase     3.80e-41   800
 3 AAF73695.1       288   800 empty       3.80e-41   800
 4 ABG85315.1         1    29 empty       6.40e- 4   800
 5 ABG85315.1        30   142 sCache_like 6.40e- 4   800
 6 ABG85315.1       143   177 empty       6.40e- 4   800
 7 ABG85315.1       178   231 HAMP        1.40e- 9   800
 8 ABG85315.1       232   241 empty       1.40e- 9   800
 9 ABG85315.1       242   341 PAS         3.80e- 3   800
10 ABG85315.1       342   800 empty       3.80e- 3   800
11 NP_224303.2        1     3 empty       3.80e-41   800
12 NP_224303.2        4   287 Pkinase     3.80e-41   800
13 NP_224303.2      288   800 empty       3.80e-41   800
14 WP_010882745.1     1     3 empty       3.80e-41   800
15 WP_010882745.1     4   287 Pkinase     3.80e-41   800
16 WP_010882745.1   288   800 empty       3.80e-41   800
```

Comment: Thanks for the ask. To the same ds I posted here as exactly as you wrote, I've got this error `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column c(start, end) must be length 4 (the number of rows) or one, not 8`

Comment: That's with a different dataset, presumably?

Comment: No, it is exactly the dataset I pass in the question. the problem is in `unest` function. I loaded the df like this `df <- structure(list(acc = c("AAF73695.1" "NP_224303.2", "WP_010882745.1", 
"ABG85315.1", "ABG85315.1", "ABG85315.1"), domain = c("Pkinase", 
"Pkinase", "Pkinase", "sCache_like", "HAMP", "PAS"), start = c(4, 
4, 4, 30, 178, 242), end = c(287, 287, 287, 142, 231, 341), evalue = c(3.8e-41, 
3.8e-41, 3.8e-41, 0.00064, 1.4e-09, 0.0038), len = c(800, 800, 
800, 800, 800, 800)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L))`

Comment: I am using the latest version of `tidyverse`, which I think includes a change in the use of `unnest`.  If you are on an older version, try `unnest(start,end)` instead.

Comment: For the final table, I needed to `unest ` separately for `start` and `end` columns and join them. Somehow I was getting this error `> rlang::last_error()
<error>
message: All nested columns must have the same number of elements.
class:   `rlang_error`
backtrace:
  1. tidyr::unnest(., start, end)
 10. tidyr::unnest(., start, end)` but in the end, I got the same list of all combinations of `starts` and `end`, for a huge table with dozens of lines (~56M) it spend some time but it worked fine, thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked! If you update `tidyverse` it might work better with the new format for `unnest`.